# Moq setup returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, moq

So, I'm starting to learn an implement UniTesting on a Web Api project I'm working on. What's happening is that when I setup a mock a call this one returns null instead of the value I'm telling to returns. I don't know why a similiar Setup works but this one just doesn't.

Here is my Test Class

```
namespace API.Tests.Web
{
    [TestClass]
    public class MaterialsControllerTest
    {
        private MaterialsController controller;
        private Mock<IRTWRepository> repository;
        private Mock<IModelFactory> factory;
        private Mock<IRTWAPIIdentityService> identityService;
        List<MaterialAccepted> materials;
        MaterialAccepted material;      

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            repository = new Mock<IRTWRepository>();
            factory = new Mock<IModelFactory>();          
            identityService = new Mock<IRTWAPIIdentityService>();
            controller = new MaterialsController(repository.Object);
            material = new MaterialAccepted()
            {
                business = true,
                businessService = EnumRecycleCenterService.Dropoff,
                residential = false,
                residentialService = EnumRecycleCenterService.Pickup,
                note = "this a note",
                Category = new Category()
                {
                    name = "Books"
                }
            };

            materials = new List<MaterialAccepted>()
                {
                    new MaterialAccepted() { business=true,businessService=EnumRecycleCenterService.Dropoff,residential=false,residentialService=EnumRecycleCenterService.Pickup,note="this a note"},
                    new MaterialAccepted() { business=false,businessService=EnumRecycleCenterService.Dropoff,residential=true,residentialService=EnumRecycleCenterService.Pickup,note="this a note"},
                };
        }    

        [TestMethod]        
        public void Post_ShouldReturnBadRequestWhenMaterialAcceptedModelValidationFails()
        {            
            //arrange
            repository.Setup(r => r.RecycleCenterRepository.Get(3)).Returns(() => new RecycleCenter());
            controller.ModelState.AddModelError("error", "unit test error");
            //act

            var actionResult = controller.Post(2, new MaterialAcceptedModel());

            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actionResult, typeof(BadRequestResult));
        }                                        
    }
}
```

Here is the action in the Controller I'm trying to test

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("api/recyclecenters/{rcid}/materials/")]
        public IHttpActionResult Post(int rcid, [FromBody]MaterialAcceptedModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                if (model != null)
                {
                    var recycleCenter = TheRepository.RecycleCenterRepository.Get(rcid);

                    if (recycleCenter == null)
                        return NotFound();

                    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                        return BadRequest(ModelState);

                    var entity = TheModelFactory.Parse(model);

                    if (entity == null) return BadRequest("Could not read material accepted in body");

                    if (TheRepository.MaterialAcceptedRepository.Get(recycleCenter.RecycleCenterId, entity.Category.name) != null)
                        return Conflict();

                    recycleCenter.Materials.Add(entity);

                    if (TheRepository.SaveAll())
                    {
                        string locationHeader = Url.Link("Materials", new { rcid = rcid, name = model.category.ToLower() });
                        return Created<MaterialAcceptedModel>(locationHeader, TheModelFactory.Create(entity));
                    }
                    return BadRequest("Could not save to the database");
                }
                return BadRequest();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }    
        }
```

If I run this test it will fail because it returns an instancy type of NotFoundResult instead of a BadRequestResult, and this is happening because the test method stops in this line

```
if (recycleCenter == null)
    return NotFound();
```

But this test it suppose to stop on this line

```
 if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      return BadRequest(ModelState);
```

Any ideas why this

```
 repository.Setup(r => r.RecycleCenterRepository.Get(3)).Returns(() => new RecycleCenter());
```

is returning null when it should return a new RecycleCenter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are setting up the repository mock for rcid = 3, and calling the repository in the controller with rcid = 2.

```
        //arrange
        repository.Setup(r => r.RecycleCenterRepository.Get(3)).Returns(() => new RecycleCenter());
        controller.ModelState.AddModelError("error", "unit test error");
        //act

        var actionResult = controller.Post(2, new MaterialAcceptedModel());
```

Try calling it with rcid = 3

```
        var actionResult = controller.Post(3, new MaterialAcceptedModel());
```

or change the Moq setup parameter to `It.IsAny<int>()`